# Most efficient algorithm to detect more than one sequence of 4 same letters horizontally, vertically or diagonally

Tags: java, string

I have been assigned a task to write an algorithm to detect if a given array of strings contains more than one sequence of 4 repeated letters horizontally, vertically or diagonally. They also asked me the most efficient way to do it.

An input example would be something like this:

`String[] input = {"ATGCGA","CAGTGC","TTATGT","AGAAGG","CCCCTA","TCACTG"};`

but you guys can see it more clearly like a table here:

```
A T G C G A
C A G T G C
T T A T G T
A G A A G G
C C C C T A
T C A C T G
```

This array contains 3 sequences with a repeated letter:

AAAA is found diagonally
CCCC is found horizontally
GGGG is found vertically

So, since there are more than 1 sequence found in this input example, the output should be true.

I have an idea to solve this problem but my major issue is handling the diagonals, especially using an efficient way to do it since they expect to use this function in a high concurrency environment.

I would be grateful for any help provided. It's ok if someone can't write the code, but at least some ideas to get the right approach to solve this problem.

I am thankful already!

Comment: `String[] input` Are you sure this is PHP and not java?

Comment: you're right @weegee I just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your current code? What resources are shared between the concurrent threads? I cannot suggest improvements without knowing what the current algorithm is.

Comment: `I have an idea to solve this problem` What is it? Elaborate on `high concurrency environment` please?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet with this is to analyze the problem first.

Identify what constitutes a diagonal.  In this case, both the row and column indices increase by 1 as the diagonal is traversed.

Next, you have a few rules that must be enforced.  Based on the diagonal length of 4, there's a maximum row/column position at which any diagonal could start. For efficiency, you should only traverse those indices which could possibly lead to a match.

To put this visually, any of these X positions in the matrix could be the start of a repeated sequence:

```
X X X O O O
X X X O O O
X X X O O O
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
```

So for this 6x6 matrix with 36 characters, we're only going to look at a maximum of 9 possible diagonal lines of length 4.

Now that we're only diagonals that could qualify the length requirement, the next step is to simply walk down the diagonal and compare each next value to the starting value.  For further efficiency, we can stop checking a diagonal as soon as it no longer matches the starting character.

Here's one way how it might play out in code:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    // Find diagonal duplicates (AAAA) starting at (0, 0)
    String[] input = {"ATGCGA","CAGTGC","TTATGT","AGAAGG","CCCCTA","TCACTG"};
    findSequences(input);

    // Find diagonal duplicates (AAAA) starting at (2,2)
    String[] input2 = {"BTGCGA","CCGTGC","TTATGT","AGAAGG","CCCCAA","TCACTA"};
    findSequences(input2);

    // Find diagonal duplicates (ZZZZ) starting at (1,2)
    String[] input3 = {"BTGCGA","CCZTGC","TTCZGT","AGAAZG","CCCCAZ","TCACTA"};
    findSequences(input3);
}


private static void findSequences(String ...input) {
    // sought-after length of repeated characters
    int repeatLength = 4;

    // max row a diagonal of length 'repeatLength' could start at
    int maxStartRow = input.length - repeatLength;

    // max column a diagonal could start at... assumes all rows have same length.
    int maxStartColumn = input[0].length() - repeatLength;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxStartRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= maxStartColumn; j++) {
            boolean allMatch = true;
            char[] sequence = new char[repeatLength];
            // Capture the starting character
            sequence[0] = input[i].charAt(j);
            // Walk down the diagonal from the starting character
            // ceasing when the characters no longer match or we exceed the length
            for (int diagonalCounter = 1; diagonalCounter < repeatLength && allMatch; diagonalCounter++) {
                sequence[diagonalCounter]= input[i+diagonalCounter].charAt(j+diagonalCounter);
                allMatch &= (sequence[0] == sequence[diagonalCounter]);
            }
            if (allMatch) {
                System.out.println("Match " + String.valueOf(sequence) + " found, starting at (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Prints:**

```
Match AAAA found, starting at (0, 0)
Match AAAA found, starting at (2, 2)
Match ZZZZ found, starting at (1, 2)
```